# Angular Bootstrap Tabs change url after tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I use [Bootstrap's Tabs](http://blog.xebia.com/bootstraps-tabs-and-lazy-data-loading-in-angularjs/) in my project. After a tab is clicked, I would like the url to change, like this:

```
/home/first
/home/second
```

But I don't know how to fix it. Here is my `$routeProvider` code:

```
  $routeProvider
      .when('/:appId/home', {
        templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
      })
      .when('/:appId/home/first', {
        templateUrl: 'app/home/first/first.html',
        controller: 'firstController'
      })
```

**UPD**
Directive code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('bootstrap.tabset', [])
.directive('tabset', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.templateUrl = '';

      var tabs = $scope.tabs = [];
      var controller = this;

      this.selectTab = function (tab) {
        angular.forEach(tabs, function (tab) {
          tab.selected = false;
        });
        tab.selected = true;
      };

      this.setTabTemplate = function (templateUrl) {
        $scope.templateUrl = templateUrl;
      };

      this.addTab = function (tab) {
        if (tabs.length == 0) {
          controller.selectTab(tab);
        }
        tabs.push(tab);
      };
    },
    template:
      '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
          '<div class="nav nav-tabs" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
          '<ng-include src="templateUrl">' +
        '</ng-include></div>' +
      '</div>'
  };
})
.directive('tab', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    require: '^tabset',
    scope: {
      title: '@',
      templateUrl: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsetController) {
      tabsetController.addTab(scope);

      scope.select = function () {
        tabsetController.selectTab(scope);
      }

      scope.$watch('selected', function () {
        if (scope.selected) {
          tabsetController.setTabTemplate(scope.templateUrl);
        }
      });
    },
    template:
      '<li ng-class="{active: selected}">' +
        '<a href="" ng-click="select()">{{ title }}</a>' +
      '</li>'
  };
});
```

**Home page HTML:**

```
<tabset>
    <tab title="Tab 1" template-url="/app/home/first/first.html"></tab>
    <tab title="Tab 1" template-url="/app/home/home.html"></tab>
</tabset>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('frontend', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'localytics.directives'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
     .when('/:appId/home', {
        templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
      })
      .when('/:appId/home/first', {
        templateUrl: 'app/home/first/first.html',
        controller: 'firstController'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  })
```

Comment: It would be easier to help solve your problem if you could post some more code, preferably a working demo..

Comment: @atefth I updated my question

Comment: Can you also post your app.js and controller code?

Comment: @atefth I updated again my question

Comment: @TarasKovalenko have you checked ui-router

Comment: @pramodkadam yes, all work, but reload all page, but I need reload just some place to html page when I paste my tabset component/

Comment: Yes, I think you better use ui.bootstrap, it's really simple and I think that's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @atefth I found good component https://github.com/rpocklin/ui-router-tabs

Comment: @TarasKovalenko ui-router have multiple options for that it will not reload all page but if parent routes have any api call then it will get all data but we can stop that call and will use only some calls

Comment: @TarasKovalenko it seems ui-router-tabs leverages both ui.bootstrap and ui.router..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a plunker I found of someone doing exactly what you want to do: http://embed.plnkr.co/TMN3KNlS4Dv90SvbTQKJ/

```
<div ng-controller="TabCtrl">
  <tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" select="onTabSelected(tab.slug)">
      {{ tab.content }}
    </tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/', {
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
      }).when('/room/:id', {
          controller: 'RoomCtrl',
      }).when('/dashboard', {
          controller: 'DashboardCtrl'            
      }).otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
      });
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
  }]);    

  var TabCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.tabs = [{
      slug: 'dashboard',
      title: "Dashboard",
      content: "Your Dashboard"
    }, {
      slug: 'room-1',
      title: "Room 1",
      content: "Dynamic content 1"
    }, {
      slug: 'room-2',
      title: "Room 2",
      content: "Dynamic content 2"
    }];
  };

  RoomCtrl = function($scope, $location) {

  };

  DashboardCtrl = function($scope, $location) {

  };    

  MainCtrl = function($scope, $location) {

    $scope.onTabSelected = function(tab) {
      var route;
      if (typeof tab === 'string') {
        switch (tab) {
          case 'dashboard':
            route = tab;
            break;
          default:
            route = 'rooms/' + tab;
            break;
        }
      }
      $location.path('/' + route);
    };

  };
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

After seen your question I think angular default router will not solve your problem.

Instead angular-routes please check ui-router it is 3rd party router supports multiple views and subview

[Ui-router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router)

for sample app check it on :

[ui-router sample app](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/)

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to achieve can be easily done using [ui.bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs).

> It's really easy to use and you don't need to write your own directive. Do check out the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vNeKWxu0uXU6ajleOWs9?p=preview).

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
    { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true }
  ];

  $scope.alertMe = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $window.alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
    });
  };

  $scope.model = {
    name: 'Tabs'
  };
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not sure that with url will change.

Comment: I think the OP wants to use tabs to load his templates and also change the url and that can be achieved with ui.bootstrap but ui.router will only change the state and thus render a new template in the ui-view directive..

Comment: it is same what you did with controller any ways all have their own views